# How to range.find a value in a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, merge, excel-2010

I have a worksheet with merged cells (e.g. B2:C3 with value "myValue"). If I try to search for a value which is in a merged cell with

```
r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveWorksheets.Range("$A:$D").Find("myValue")
Debug.Print r.Address
```

I only get the address of other single cells with similar values but not of the merged cell.

How can I do this with VBA? If I use the manual search function of Excel it finds the value in no time.

Best regards,
Harry

EDIT: When I use the code from Gary I get a runtime error 91. The variable r is Nothing.

[image]

Comment: Range("B2:C3").Cells(1).Value ? may serve the purpose. Alternatively ~Range("B2").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value~ If you do not know bounds of the merged area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up a few things:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim r As Range

    Call Setup
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$D").Find("myValue")
    Debug.Print r.Address
End Sub

Sub Setup()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("B2:C3")

    With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With

    rng.Value = "MyValue"
End Sub
```

Will get you the **upper left-hand corner** of the merged area:

[image]

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? I use Excel 2010. May be that's the problem :(

Comment: @HarryKane  I am using *Excel 2007* with *Windows 7*

Comment: Your example is what I expected, but as you can see in my edit, it does not work. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I'm using excel 2010 (14.0) too. Range.find with merged cells (like in Gary's code) works fine.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It works for me with discrete range (e.g. $A1:$D20) but not with complete rows ($2:$2 or Rows(2)) nor columns ($B:$B or Columns(2)).

Comment: @HarryKane  I think Excel can get confused if the merged area spans more than row or column.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `MergeArea` for such cases:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.[A:D].Find("myValue")
    Debug.Print r.MergeArea.Address
End Sub
```